# D3 Accessing array in Json object to attribute

Tags: arrays, json, d3.js, attr

In my data for force layout I have

```
"nodes":[
    {"id":"0", "name":"A",
    "isListedIn":["USSDN","Canadian list"] 
    },
```

Normally, I would then bind it to D3 selection such as

```
d3.select(body).selectAll(".node").data(graph.nodes).enter()
    .append("image")
    .attr("name") function(d) return d.name) 
    .attr("isListedIn",function(d) return d.isListedIn)
```

Where I try to get it out

```
 var listList=d3.select("#listList").append("ul")
        .data(listList)
        .enter()
        .append("li")
        .text(function(d){return d})
```

But d.isListedIn is not working. The thing I tried to do is when user click on 1 node--> I can get the value of isListedIn out as a array. How can I achieve this?

Comment: this is a strange code `d3.select(body).data(graph.nodes).enter()
    .attr("name") function(d) return d.name) ` you are not appending any thing. I am wondering if the force graph is working. Can you post a working fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, there were mistakes in the code. I shall edit it now. But the point is that I do not know how to access array nested inside d.isListedIn

Comment: Frankly this should work may be inside the function you can console to check if d has `isListedIn` ... something like this  `.attr("isListedIn",function(d) {console.log(d);return d.isListedIn)} `

Comment: @Cyril: It does work. But my attr("isListedIn") now  has a string from d.isListedIn, not an array. When I used text(node.attr("isListedIn")) in order to make a list of List, it only a string

Comment: @edit: Added code where I want to get it out for more clues

Comment: you define a `listList` variable to which you provide a `.data(listList)` variable with the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

It doesn't really makes sense to add an attribute to store the isListedIn list on your nodes just to retrieve it later, as d3 already does that for you. If you want to get the data for a DOM element, you can use either `d3.select('#el').data()[0]['isListedIn']` or `d3.select('#el').each(function(d) { console.log(d.isListedIn); });` depending on what you want to do with it.